# How can I reinstall a Kernel version?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I’m currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and my Kernel version 5.19.0.35 is no longer responsive after trying to install the Nvidia driver 525 recommended by my terminal with the command ‘ubuntu-drivers devices’.

By not responsive I mean, whenever I try to boot it, I’m only left with a black screen with an unresponsive blinking underscore in the upper left corner, and pressing Ctrl + Alt + F 1 - 12 does nothing, and it’s for this reason that I wonder if reinstalling the kernel is a good option, and also how to do it properly, I’ve only found older posts and I need something more updated.

Just as an extra bit of context, my GPU is a Geforce 1650 Mobile, and my computer a Lenovo Gaming 3 15ARH05.

'lspci | grep VGA' output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev ff)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c6)
```

'find /dev -group video' output:

```
/dev/media0
/dev/video1
/dev/video0
/dev/fb0
```

'glxinfo | grep -i vendor' output:

```
Error: unable to open display
```

'lsmod | grep nouveau' output:

```
nouveau              2367488  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
drm_ttm_helper         16384  2 amdgpu,nouveau
ttm                    98304  3 amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
drm_display_helper    184320  2 amdgpu,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        200704  5 drm_display_helper,amdgpu,nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,nouveau
drm                   581632  9     gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,n    ouveau
wmi                    32768  4 wmi_bmof,ideapad_laptop,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  65536  2 ideapad_laptop,nouveau
```

Used these commands in kernel v. 5.19.0.35 recovery mode to see what driver was installed, perhaps I had none and that's why GUI wasn't even loading, these were the results.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a kernel issue, it is an nvidia driver issue.   You can probably disable the nvidia driver by putting `nomodeset` on the kernel command line.  You need to include information about which nvidia card you have in your question for further help.

Comment: @user10489 Just added my GPU information. Problem about the drivers is that I already purged them from recovery mode, but still I get the unresponsive black screen.

Comment: So now you do not have a driver for the video card?

Comment: You always have a driver for the video card.  If you purged the nvidia drivers, you probably have the nouveau driver which is notorious for giving black screens and locking up the keyboard with cards it doesn't understand.  nomodeset will disable that and leave you with a default driver that works, but probably poorly.

Comment: @David I added some extra information in the question, with a couple commands to see if I have a driver installed on .35 or not, since I'm pretty new to Ubuntu, I'm unsure as to whether this clarifies something or not.

Comment: @user10489 What's odd is that, I purged the drivers from both kernel v. 5.19.0.35 and .32, but the latter works perfectly with the Nouveau driver, and .35 doesn't boot up. I already checked and there are no Nvidia drivers installed in either of 'em.

Comment: To be clearer you do not have a specific NVIDIA driver loaded. You may find the nomodeset info on this web site interesting. https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/grub-options.html

Comment: The nvidia driver doesn't come with the kernel, it is a dkms driver and updating it updates it for all kernels (unless yo do something special).  The nouveau driver does come with the kernel, so changing kernels might change which version of nouveau you are using.

Comment: You could try `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and then reboot.